# iOS Override Auto Layout for certain components/objects in a view

Tags: ios, overriding, autolayout

I have a view with a series of buttons underneath each other, when one of the buttons gets selected I need to programatically add onother button at the top of all the other buttons and then change the height of all the buttons so that no space is lost to the bottom of the screen.

The problem is I need auto layout turned on for this view, but because of that I can't resize, or change the position of the buttons.

My question is how can I 'overide' the autolayout of certain objects in the view (buttons) to change their layout when a button is selected.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autolayout is capable of the use case you're describing. The height of views can compress to make room for one more button.

Use `- (void)setContentCompressionResistancePriority:(UILayoutPriority)priority forAxis:(UILayoutConstraintAxis)axis` on each of the buttons and set the priority to a low number (i.e. <250). Since you have a vertical row, the axis would be `UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical`.

You will have to call `-setNeedsUpdateConstraints` on the superview of all your buttons in order for the new constraints to show up.